# Place cursor in edit control box in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, mfc, dialog

I am trying to make a password dialog box in a visual studio software. As soon as my password dialog box opens, I want the cursor to be placed in the edit control box so I can type password on it.

How can I put or place cursor in a text edit box in visual studio  MFC without a mouse click?

Please suggest me how to do this.

```
static CEdit *ptrCurrentEditWindow;

BOOL GET_PASSWORD::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    SetDlgItemText(IDC_PASSWORD, L"");
    ptrCurrentEditWindow = &m_wnd_password;

    return TRUE;  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for [CDialog::OnInitDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdialog-class#oninitdialog) explains, how to do this. The return value section has this information:

> Specifies whether the application has set the input focus to one of the controls in the dialog box. If `OnInitDialog` returns nonzero, Windows sets the input focus to the default location, **the first control in the dialog box**. The application can return 0 only if it has explicitly set the input focus to one of the controls in the dialog box.

That leaves you with 2 options:

- Make your edit control the first control, and have Windows handle everything for you by returning `TRUE`.
- Move input to your edit control manually ([CDialog::GotoDlgCtrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdialog-class#gotodlgctrl)), and return `FALSE`.

---

Addressing the updated question: The implementation already does, what you need, as long as you make `IDC_PASSWORD` the first control in your dialog template. If you do not want to or cannot arrange for this, you'll have to manually move input focus, like this:

```cpp
BOOL GET_PASSWORD::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    // Not needed; an edit control is initially empty
    SetDlgItemText(IDC_PASSWORD, L"");

    // Set input focus to the desired control
    GotoDlgCtrl(GetDlgItem(IDC_PASSWORD));
    // Let the framework know, that you already set input focus
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: SetDlgItemText(IDC_PASSWORD, L" ");    i have given like this in OnInitDialog Box, but cursor is not placed in edit control box. I have to manually do it using mouse click

Comment: If you cannot arrange for the first option, then go with the second option. Either one works, regardless of you changing the contents of the control. If you want to do it the hard way, just replace your final line of code in your implementation with this: `GotoDlgCtrl(GetDlgItem(IDC_PASSWORD)); return FALSE;`. As an aside, having a static member variable pointing to a UI element in a dialog is *very* uncommon. And will inevitably cause you grief. Whatever problem this is trying to solve, this probably isn't a solution.

Comment: I also just want to mention as a side point when setting the tab order you can use CTRL + SHIFT when you click on your first number. This will leave the tab order up to and include that control "as is" and then you can go on and click on the rest of the controls. This is handy if you only want to adjust the tab order for the last view controls or just a few part way in the tab order.